# Current through capacitors

Tags: capacitor

There is a question like,

Assume the voltage source connected across the series-connected capacitors as 50∠0 rms, 50Hz. The voltage source has a capacity of 100VA. Calculate the current passing through the capacitors.

For this, my solution is S = 100VA, and so the Irms = S/Vrms = 100/50 = 2A. Not sure whether I am in a right path? Could anyone please assist me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Capacity is irrelevant if it is not exceeded. Think of impedance.

Comment: 2A is the max current the source can provide. The actual current depends on the capacitor value. Ohms law for AC: V = I*Z

Answer (score 2):

First find the impedance offered the capacitors. Two capacitors C1 and C2 in series will produce an impedance,  \$Z = \dfrac{1}{j\omega C_1} + \dfrac{1}{j\omega C_2}\$.

Then calculate the current, \$I= V/Z\$.

Now the current through the capacitors \$\mathrm{= min(I,I_{max})}\$. Where \$I_{max}\$ is the maximum current the supply can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Either something got lost in translation or you were given a "trick question".

- With any equation with N variables there must be either N equations , you have none
- for N= 4 variables to the capacitor impedance equation you provided only 1 "useful" values to solve for the remaining 3. (C,V,f,I)
- You are given a series of capacitors in series (with nothing specified) which cannot have a voltage source applied in parallel since the loop is not specified.

On two counts the question is insolvable or illogical, without the value of C and V. (Not just VA)

**If you are trying to design a circuit, tell us the objective , purpose and desired goal and what you did , then ask how to achieve it if possible.**  add to question.